# spl_autoload_register in different directories

Tags: php

```
/htdocs
    /classes
        DB.class.php
        USER.class.php
    /core
        init.php
    /ajax
        data.php
    /require
    ....
    ....

    index.php
```

inside `init.php` I have this function.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
           require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
    });
```

The problem is that I have this USER class which needs some other classes (database class etc) and is used in some files inside `ajax` folder and in some files in the `require` folder. If I fix the require path for init.php in the `USER` class to use it for a file in the `require` folder it does not work for a file in `ajax` folder and vice-versa.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
warning: require_once(../core/init.php): failed to open stream: no such file or directory in c:\apache24\htdocs\classes\user.class.php on line 3
```

this is `USER` class

```
Line 3: require_once 'core/init.php';
```

Comment: `require_once '/core/init.php';` ?

Comment: It doesn't work. I have considered using an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define multiple include paths

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
define('BP', dirname(__FILE__));

$paths = array(
    BP . DS . 'classes',
    BP . DS . 'core',
    BP . DS . 'ajax',
    get_include_path()
);

$includePaths = implode(PS, $paths);
set_include_path($includePaths);
```